# Proper use of inStream() and and actualStream() in Modelica when no volume present

Tags: modelica

I have used the Modelica "stream" concept for connectors for some time. What I understand the functions inStream() and actualStream() are designed for  use
when the model has a volume.  But here are important cases where there is no
volume and you need for convenience stick to the connectors you have. One example is a  ProbeSensor that is mounted into a reactor volume and measures one of the species in the liquid, but does not "consume" any liquid.

The code below works using inStream(). However, I am inclined to instead use actualStream() since it "handles  zero flow". But if I do the change the model does not compile and I get translation error that here are more variable than equations.

Is the code with inStream() after all correct?
Or how should it be modified?

```
LiquidCon
   stream Real[2] c;
   flow Real F;
   Real p;
end LiquidCon;

block ProbeSensor
   LiquidCon probe;
   output RealOutput out;
   constant Integer component = 2         "The liquidphase component measured index";
   parameter Real T (unit="h")  = 0.05    "Time constant of measurement";
   parameter Real x_0  = 0.0              "Initial state of measurement device";
   Real x(start=x_0, fixed=true)          "State variable measurement device";
   Real p (unit="bar")                    "Pressure";
equation
   probe.F = 0;
   p = probe.p;
   for i in 1:2 loop 
      if (i==component) then
         T*der(x) + x = inStream(probe.c[component]);
         inStream(probe.c[component]) = probe.c[component];
         out = x;
      else  
         inStream(probe.c[i]) = probe.c[i];             
      end if;
   end for;                             
end ProbeSensor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `inStream()` is the best solution for this type of sensor/probe model.

`inStream()` gives you a value for the **hypothetical** case of fluid streaming into the component model. No matter what the real flow direction is (in this case 0 flow). And that's perfectly right for sensors.

As a general rule: If you can do something with `inStream()` than go for it. Only use `actualStream()` if you really need it.

Reason for that: `actualStream()` is basically an if expression. And that is always nonlinear, which can easily produce ugly nonlinear systems in the overall system model.

Comment: i see that Modelica specification 3.5 in appendix C 3.3 discusses a similar  "ProbeSensor" application and they do not bother about zero flow and no volume and still use inStream(). In section 15.3 they  recommend using actualStream() when it is multiplied with the associated flow, as you do in mass balance equations.

Comment: It's stated in the section's heading: "where one mass flow rate is identical to zero".
It's only recommended to additionally set the min attribute of the flow variable to 0. I guess the reason is Modelica tools will take the min attribute into account to simplify the equation system resulting from a stream connection set.

But you would still need the equation flow_variable=0 in the equation section. Otherwise your component is not locally balanced (# unknowns = # equations).